# Sign convention for Maxwell's model of viscoelastic material

Tags: material-science, conventions, elasticity, viscosity

Maxwell's equation for viscoelastic body is $\dot{\varepsilon}(t)=\frac{\dot{\sigma}}{E}(t)+\frac{\sigma}{\eta}(t)$, where $\varepsilon=\frac{dl}{l}$ is strain and $\sigma$ is stress. I am a little bit confused about sign convention in this equation.

1. **Sign convention for ε**: What sign corresponds to extension type of deformation and what sign corresponds to compression type of deformation?
2. **Sign convention for σ**: What sign corresponds to pulling external pressure and what sign corresponds to squeezing external pressure?

Comment: The signs in the equation (as written) apply to both extension and compression.  If the body is being compressed, the values of $\epsilon$ and $\sigma $will come out negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since strain is defined by
\begin{align}
\epsilon = \frac{\Delta l}{l} = \frac{l - l_0}{l}
\end{align}
where $l_0$ is the initial length of the object, you can
see what the sign should be. Be careful with expressions
like $\epsilon = \text{d}l/l$ since this is not an equality
because a differential can only be equal to a differential of
the same order.

For $\sigma$ the convention is a minus sign for compressing and
a plus sign for pulling.